# How to convert string to date format in Oracle

Tags: sql, datetime, oracle11g, timestamp

I have a file contains a string like `2011-03-14 11:57:42+08:00` and I need to store it in a column with `DATE` datatype. I use Oracle 11g.

I have tried `TO_DATE` function but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why did TO_DATE not work? What format parameter did you use?

Comment: to_date should work, show us the query.

Comment: I use this query `SELECT TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (2011-03-14 11:57:42+08:00, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS my_date FROM DUAL`
what I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the function `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` to get the timezone properly parsed:

```
SELECT CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2011-03-14 11:57:42+08:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS+TZH:TZM') AS DATE) AS my_date 
  FROM DUAL
 ;
```

(And as a side note to your example in the comment: no need for `TO_CHAR`, quoting was missing and format model `MON` (abbreviated month) was incorrect)